# How should I take an input, check against a dictionary, and if it matches replace with the definition?

Tags: c#

What would be the best way to take an input, check against a dictionary, and if it matches replace with the definition?

I'm trying to make a morse code converter, and I've decided to use a dictionary to store the morse translations. I'm struggingling to think of the best way to check the dictionary against an input though.

I could do something like...

```
If unconvertedInput = morseDic commaMorse
```

However, that would be terribly inefficient I think. Or is a dictionary not the way to go here? I'm just not sure.

Also here is my incomplete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MorseCodeConverter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> morseDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            morseDictonary.Add(" ", " ");
            morseDictonary.Add(",", "--..--");
            morseDictonary.Add(".", ".-.-.-");

            string spaceMorse = morseDictonary[" "];
            string commaMorse = morseDictonary[","];
            string periodMorse = morseDictonary["."];
            MessageBox.Show(spaceMorse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could u give a sample input and output?

Comment: Presumably you'd only be replacing one character at a time, right? Sounds like you should create a new StringBuilder and walk through the input one character at a time, appending either the original character or the value in the dictionary. As an aside, your dictionary is going to be the same every time the button is pressed - so you might as well have it in a static variable.

Comment: do you want to convert morse code to text or the other way round

Comment: why do you think it's inefficient ? You would do the similar operation even in real life. in fact, i've been warned many times that this type of questions might get down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way:

```
var morseDictonary = new Dictionary<char, string>()
{
    { '.', ".-.-.-" },
    { ',', "--..--" },
    { ' ', " " },
    { 'A', ".-" },
    { 'B', "-..." },
};

var example = "A , B .";

var result = String.Join("", example.Select(x => morseDictonary[x]));
```

I get this result:

> .- --..-- -... .-.-.-

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want a *static* variable for the dictionary, as that's not going to change over time. I'd then use a `StringBuilder` to build up the result, rather than trying to replace text *within* the string. (Strings are immutable, making that a tricky proposition anyway - and life is often simpler when you keep input and output strictly separated.)

In terms of efficiency, using a `StringBuilder` is going to be fine - and the dictionary lookups will be very efficient. If you know that you're only dealing with ASCII text, you *could* have a `string[]` and index it by ASCII value instead, and that would be even more efficient... but I would stick to the dictionary for now unless you're translating *huge* amounts of text. (It will still happen in the blink of an eye for any sensible amount of text.)

```
public class MorseCodeTranslationForm
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> Translations =
        new Dictionary<char, string>
        {
            { 'A', ".-" },
            { 'B', "-..." },
            // etc 
        };

    // Normal constructor etc

    // Call this from an event handler...
    private static string ConvertToMorse(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            string translated;
            if (Translations.TryGetValue(c, out translation))
            {
                builder.Append(translated).Translate(' ');
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(c); // Just leave it as it is                    
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

(You might also want to separate the UI code from the "business logic" of morse translation, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

Note that you have to do the period (.) first, and you cannot convert dashes (-), if not they will get replaced too.

```
        Dictionary<string, string> morseDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        morseDictonary.Add(".", ".-.-.-");  //*** Important: Do this first ***
        morseDictonary.Add(",", "--..--");
        morseDictonary.Add(" ", " ");
        morseDictonary.Add("A", ".-");
        morseDictonary.Add("B", "-...");
        //...

        string example = "A , B .";

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in morseDictonary)
        {
            example = example.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        //example = ".- --..-- -... .-.-.-"
```

Comment: This method seems to be the cleanest. However, I tried that, and it [outputs "A, B .-.-.-"](https://i.imgur.com/yvlBq0j.png).